# Can I initialize a list from an expression in a simple way, similar to Python?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, initialization

Let's say I have a function that returns an object:

```cs
public object toto() {}
```

Or in python:

```py
def toto():
    return "something"
```

I want to initialize a list of `n` elements in a very simple way, in Python I would do:

```py
l = [toto() for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

Is there a simple, similar way, of doing that in C#, avoiding loops ?

Thanks !

Comment: What exactly you want to return? In C# you should avoid `object`

Comment: By "avoid loops" you mean not writing the loop yourself? Because under the hood it's always going to have a loop.

Comment: FYI, a list comprehension in python doesn't "avoid loops". The loop is right there for you to see: `for i in ...`. A list comprehension is simply _syntactic sugar_ for a loop whose only job is to build a list.

Comment: I know it's a loop, it's just clearer in the writing. But thanks for the precision.
I am also not returning "object", it's just for the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-7.0):

```
var l = Enumerable.Range(0, n + 1).Select(i => "something" + i);
```

If you want to "consume" it you could use a `foreach`:

```
foreach(string s in l)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

or create a new `List<string>` or `string[]`:

```
List<string> stringList = l.ToList();
string[] stringArray = l.ToArray();
```

That of courses also uses loops, just you don't see them.

Note that if you often need to use it, you should really create a collection from it(as shown above). Otherwise you will always execute the LINQ query ([`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0) is using deferred execution). Read this blog to understand the concept: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you/

Comment: So: Enumerable.Range(0, n + 1).Select(i => "something" + i).ToList(); would do it, thanks !